# Why does a bridge interface need an IP?

Tags: ip, qemu, bridge

I create a network bridge interface, then start several QEMU instances which add tap devices to that bridge. I found that these instances cannot ping each other until I assign an IP address to the bridge device itself (on the host). I don't understand that behaviour - I expected a bridge to establish a layer 2 connection between the virtual network cards. Why is an IP address on the bridge interface itself necessary?

Comment: Can you verify this command returns nothing (an error) or 0, but not 1? `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables`? And also are the VMs sharing the same LAN (eg: 192.168.122.0/24) and not using different LANs (with too narrow CIDR instead of /24 etc.)?

Comment: Even better if you provided a reproducible setup with the steps you did, this would help further checking. Also QEMU runs on a lot of platforms. I assumed Linux in previous comment but I might be wrong.

Comment: After you've created the bridge does the physical interface still have an IP address? If so, remove it

Comment: Are you ensuring that your virtual machine interfaces have different MAC addresses? This goes back to what A.B was saying about providing a reproducible example so that we understand your configuration. A bridge does **not** require an ip address in order to provide layer 2 connectivity, but without knowing exactly how you've configured things we can't tell you what needs to change.